# How to intercept proceed() in another AspectJ aspect?

Tags: aop, aspectj, pointcut

I have a situation as follows: I have a `LoggingAspect` with several pointcuts matching specific method executions in my main application. The corresponding advice bodies basically all look similar, causing a lot of code duplication:

```java
void around() : download() {
    String message = "Downloading, verifying (MD5) and unpacking";
    SimpleLogger.verbose(message, IndentMode.INDENT_AFTER);
    proceed();
    SimpleLogger.verbose(message + " - done", IndentMode.DEDENT_BEFORE);
}
```

There is some variation, though. Sometimes the pointcut & advice have an `arg` or `this` parameter which is also printed to the log. Sometimes the "done" message is not printed if it s just a minor call not wrapping a lot of other calls, like this:

```java
void around(BasicFilter filter) : fixFaultyLinkTargets()  && this(filter) {
    String message = "TOC file: checking for faulty link targets";
    SimpleLogger.verbose(message, IndentMode.INDENT_AFTER);
    proceed(filter);
    SimpleLogger.dedent();
}
```

The constant thing is that I manually tell the logger

- to increase the indent level after the first message is printed, i.e. directly before `proceed()` is called, and
- to decrease the indent level before the final message is printed (if any is printed), i.e. directly after `proceed()` has returned.

My idea is that I would like to write a meta aspect (or call it a helper aspect) with a pointcut which intercepts the `proceed()` calls in `LoggingAspect` so as to automatically adjust the indentation level accordingly. But there seems to be no pointcut matching `proceed()`. I have tried `call(SomeMethodInMyMainApp)`, even a pointcut matching everything in the logging aspect, but the pointcut matches anything I do not need, but never ever the proceed.

If anybody knows how I can do this, I would appreciate a hint or a code snippet.

An indirect way of doing this might be to intercept not the advice themselves, but the method calls (or executions) advised by those advice by creating an extra pointcut like this:

```java
// ATTENTION: each new pointcut must also be added here
pointcut catchAll() : download() || fixFaultyLinkTargets() || ...;

void around() : catchAll() {
    SimpleLogger.indent();
    proceed();
    SimpleLogger.dedent();
}
```

I would prefer another way though, without me having to remember to update the extra `catchAll()` pointcut everytime I change something in the logging aspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion wrap the proceed() in an anonymous class. And the write an aspect which adress this execution (but don't forget potential exceptions of proceed()).

My suggestion:

```java
// AspectProceedCaller.java
public abstract class AspectProceedCaller { 
    public abstract Object doProceed(); 
};

// aspect ProceedCallerAspect.aj
aspect ProceedCallerAspect {
     pointcut execProceedCaller() : execution( * AspectProceedCaller+.doProceed() );

     Object around() : execProceedCaller() {
         try {
              SimpleLogger.indent();
              return proceed();
         }
         finally {
              SimpleLogger.dedent();
         }
     }
};


// Your application aspect 
aspect AnyAspect {
    pointcut anyPointcut() : ...;

    Object around() : anyPointcut() {
        AspectProceedCaller apc=new AspectProceedCaller() {
            public Object doProceed() {
                return proceed();
            }
        };  

        // DO Stuff before ....

        Object retval = apc.doProceed();

        // ... and after calling proceed.

        return retval;
    }
};
```

Best regards Marko

Comment: While this is a creative and even working approach to intercept `proceed()`, my goal stated above to avoid code duplication cannot be achieved by this because I in order to avoid the duplicate logging & indentation code, I have to trade it for duplicate anonymous class declarations. Obviously I cannot declare the anonymous class as a singleton outside of an advice and reuse it because then I would not be able to call `proceed()` anymore. And I have many logging advice... So I am sorry for not choosing your answer, because it is still open. Thanks a lot anyway. :-)

Comment: Update: I have upvoted your answer because I am using a similar approach now. It is not what I want, but less bad than what I had before. See [this changeset](https://github.com/kriegaex/Galileo-Openbook-Cleaner/commit/2de815517e8b44139bed7a519dd7629a8a47511b) and the two corresponding versions of my `LoggingAspect` for information about what it looked like before and after my refactoring. Thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: There is no other possibility IMHO, cause proceed() is not a function. It's a reserved keyword within an around advice and it's not a joinpoint.

Comment: ... And there is little chance that this could be changed, because AspectJ must be able to weave aspects into JAR or LTW. Marko

Comment: I know it is not a joinpoint, as I have said in my original post: "there seems to be no pointcut matching proceed()". But I see no reason why it could not be made one by the AJ developers. Member variable assignment is no function call either, but is a joinpoint anyway. The cost would probably be to keep some extra state (if the necessary information is not already available in the joinpoint's metadata). Let me keep this question open for a while and if I get no better answer here or on [AspectJ users](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/msg13680.html), I might accept yours.

Comment: proceed() is a placeholder, which does not exist anymore after the around advice has been applied. proceed() has been replaced by the method, field access, ... . By the way, I've written a small blog serie about Logging/Tracing and AspectJ: [AOP und Logging](http://marko-software-developer.blogspot.ch/2009/12/aop-und-logging.html). I'm going to start with the implementation of AjLog. - Marko

Answer (score 3):

**Please note:** I am going to answer my own question here, adding more information and the additional feature of parametrisation to the solution suggested by loddar2012. Because his answer led me to the right direction, I am going to accept it even though this answer here really addresses all my needs from the original question, such as (quoting myself):

> There is some variation, though. Sometimes the pointcut & advice have an arg or this parameter which is also printed to the log. Sometimes the "done" message is not printed if it s just a minor call not wrapping a lot of other calls

The basic thing we are dealing with here is what Ramnivas Laddad calls the **worker object pattern** in his book [AspectJ in Action](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/). His (and loddar2012's) idea is, in plain prose

- to wrap a call into an instance of an anonymous class (the worker object) where

  - the base class or implemented interface provides a method intended to do the work,
  - the worker object provides a concrete implementation of the worker method and specifically calls `proceed()` therein,
  - the worker method can be called right after object creation (as we will do here) or later, maybe even in its own thread,
  - the worker object may be passed around or added to a scheduling queue (none of which we will need here).

An elegant solution if you need to execute your `proceed()` calls asynchronously would be to create instances of anonymous `Runnable` classes. We will use our own abstract base class `LogHelper`, though, because we want some more sugar in our tea, specifically the option to pass a log message and some other parameters influencing log output to each worker. So this is what I did (package names and imports not shown in the sample code):

**Abstract worker base class:**

```java
abstract class LogHelper {
    // Object state needed for logging
    String message;
    boolean logDone;
    boolean indent;
    LogType type;

    // Main constructor
    LogHelper(String message, boolean logDone, boolean indent, LogType type) {
        this.message = message;
        this.logDone = logDone;
        this.indent = indent;
        this.type = type;
    }
    // Convenience constructors for frequent use cases
    LogHelper(String message, boolean logDone) {
        this(message, logDone, true, LogType.VERBOSE);
    }
    LogHelper(String message) {
        this(message, true);
    }

    // Worker method to be overridden by each anonymous subclass
    abstract void log();
}
```

**Logging advice capturing execution of worker objects:**

```java
aspect LoggingAspect
{
    void around(LogHelper logHelper) :
        execution(* LogHelper.log()) && this(logHelper)
    {
        try {
            SimpleLogger.log(logHelper.type, logHelper.message);
            if (logHelper.indent)
                SimpleLogger.indent();
            proceed(logHelper);
        } finally {
            if (logHelper.indent)
                SimpleLogger.dedent();
            if (logHelper.logDone)
                SimpleLogger.log(logHelper.type, logHelper.message + " - done");
        }
    }
    // (...)
}
```

As you can see, the logging advice does some things before calling `proceed(logHelper)` (i.e. executing the worker object's `log()` method) and some things afterwards, using the state information stored inside the worker object, such as

- message to be logged,
- log level (here called "type"),
- flag specifying if indentation level should be raised before proceeding,
- flag specifying if "done" message should be printed after worker execution.

Because in my use case all logged methods return `void`, there is no need to implement return value passing, but this would be easily possible, if necessary. The advice's return value would then just be `Object` and we would pass the result of `proceed()` back to our caller, no big deal.

**Some advice capturing joinpoints to be logged and utilising parametrised worker objects to get the work done:**

```java
aspect LoggingAspect
{
    // (...)

    pointcut processBook()     : execution(* OpenbookCleaner.downloadAndCleanBook(Book));
    pointcut download()        : execution(* Downloader.download());
    pointcut cleanBook()       : execution(* OpenbookCleaner.cleanBook(Book));
    pointcut cleanChapter()    : execution(* OpenbookCleaner.cleanChapter(Book, File));
    pointcut initialiseTitle() : execution(* *Filter.initialiseTitle(boolean));

    void around(final Book book) : processBook() && args(book) {
        new LogHelper("Book: " + book.unpackDirectory) {
            void log() { proceed(book); } }.log();
    }
    void around() : download() {
        new LogHelper("Downloading, verifying (MD5) and unpacking") {
            void log() { proceed(); } }.log();
    }
    void around() : cleanBook() {
        new LogHelper("Filtering") {
            void log() { proceed(); } }.log();
    }
    void around(final File origFile) : cleanChapter() && args(*, origFile) {
        new LogHelper("Chapter: " + origFile.getName()) {
            void log() { proceed(origFile); } }.log();
    }
    void around() : initialiseTitle() {
        new LogHelper("Initialising page title", false) {
            void log() { proceed(); } }.log();
    }
}
```

The examples show how you can

- instantiate an anonymous `LogHelper` as a worker object with one or more constructor parameters, setting its state
- implement the `log()` method, optionally using joinpoint state bound via `this()` or `args()`,
- call/run the worker object (the call will be intercepted by the logging advice's pointcut and the real logging business be done there).

Comment: Nice exactly what I was looking for, until know I was using runnables as a workaround