# AOP Using Around to avoid executing a method

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I am using Spring AOP in my code to intercept the execution of a certain method. A simplified example of what I'm trying to do is below:

```
public void someMethod() {
    //does something
}

@Around("execution( someMethod())")
public void anotherMethod(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    //i want to add this to a queue to get executed later on
    addToWaitList(new Callable() {
        @Override
        public call() throws Exception {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        }
    });
    return;
}
```

Essentially, I want to hold off the execution of `someMethod()` until it is at the head of the list. However, the main thread blocks, even though I return at the end of `anotherMethod()`, so I am unable to add a `new Callable` to the list until the first one is done executing.

The documentation says you can shortcut the advised method execution by returning its own return value or throwing an exception. I don't want to throw an exception and am not really sure what "returning its own return value" means in this case. I want to be able to add the Callables to the list with the main thread and then have some other threadpool executing them.

Comment: Why does the main thread block?

Comment: Could you please provide a thread dump of the main thread ?

Comment: Have you considered using Spring's `@Async` annotation for this?

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What you wish to implement is the **worker object pattern**. I have created a small example for you showing how you can intercept method calls with by a certain naming pattern, but with variable return types and parameters. See [my own answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12130824/1082681) for a more complex example.

**Driver application:**

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting up application");
        Application app = new Application();
        app.doThis(11);
        app.doThat();
        app.doThis(22);
        System.out.println("Shutting down application");
    }

    public void doThis(int number) {
        System.out.println("Doing this with number " + number);
    }

    public String doThat() {
        String value = "lorem ipsum";
        System.out.println("Doing that with text value '" + value + "'");
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Aspect implementing worker object pattern:**

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class QueuedExecutionAspect {

    Queue<Callable<Object>> waitList = new LinkedList<Callable<Object>>();

    private void addToWaitList(Callable<Object> callable) {
        waitList.add(callable);
    }

    @Around("execution(public * Application.do*(..))")
    public Object anotherMethod(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println(joinPoint + " -> adding to execution queue");
        addToWaitList(new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    joinPoint.proceed();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    throw new Exception(e);
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @After("execution(public * Application.main(..))")
    public void doDelayedExecution(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("\nDelayed executions:");
        while (!waitList.isEmpty()) {
            waitList.poll().call();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Starting up application
execution(void Application.doThis(int)) -> adding to execution queue
execution(String Application.doThat()) -> adding to execution queue
execution(void Application.doThis(int)) -> adding to execution queue
Shutting down application

Delayed executions:
Doing this with number 11
Doing that with text value 'lorem ipsum'
Doing this with number 22
```

As you can see from the output, the `@Around` advice terminates normally after having added the `Callable` worker object to the queue, application execution continues without `proceed()` having been called. For illustration I added another advice which runs all elements from the FIFO queue (other queue types can be used according to your needs) before the application exits.