# Call a method before other methods

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop

I have a lot of methods that I have  to "block" if a boolean flag for the used object is true. 
I try to explain better: I've created a method that need to block some other methods because it makes some operations on database and file system and to avoid inconsistency I have to block all the other methods that use the same data.

For example:

**method A** has to change a specific fleet "123" and this operation takes long time
**method B**, **method C**, **method D** use fleet so I have to check if the request is for the fleet "123" and then return an exception.

I was wondering if there is a smarter method than `if` clause in each method, I read among design pattern but no one seems to be appropriate to my case so I thought to use a class with static methods (more than one because I have to check fleet, car or other) and call these methods before the called method, but it is possible through `annotation` for example? or by `Spring AOP`?

About AOP I don't find if it's possible to pass a parameter (I have to pass the fleet for example between the method and the Advice) and if I can use the same Advice on several methods specifing it on the method to don't forget to add a new method to the Advice.

what do you suggest?

**UPDATE**
To test AOP I create a new project and these classes:
Annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAOPAnnotation {
}
```

AOP class

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class TestAOP {

    @Before("@annotation(TestAOPAnnotation)")
    public void logAOP(){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

The method wehre I use the annotation

```
@Override
@TestAOPAnnotation
public List<Animals> findByName(String name) throws QueryException {
    try{
        return animalsRepository.findByName(name);
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new QueryException(e);
    }
}
```

and where I catch the exception

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="/test/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Animals> findByName(@PathVariable String name){
    try{
        return databaseAnimalsServices.findByName(name);
    }catch(QueryException e){
        return null;
    }catch(Exception e){
        //CATCH AOP EXCEPTION
        List<Animals> list = new ArrayList<Animals>();
        list.add(new Animals("AOP", "exception", "test"));
        return list;
    }
}
```

How can pass the parameter, in this case `String name`? I may have `Fleet` object, `fleetId`, `Car` or other but on different method becaure they require different query.

Comment: AoP seems indeed a good candidat. Searching on google net quite a few stackoverflow questions with answers for that particular problem.
Exemple : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114843/aop-using-around-to-avoid-executing-a-method

Comment: Sounds like you need a GOF Mediator

Comment: It is perfectly feasible with AOP. Now let's for a moment pretend that we were on StackOverflow, i.e. you would provide sample code (optimally runnable, not just loose snippets) showing how you would do it without AOP. Then someone would answer your question by refactoring that code into an AOP solution. How does that sound?

Comment: For this type of use case, I will use annotations, because your requirement will modify the way the method run so it should be visible to the developer. AOP can use annotation. For example you can annotate a method with `@FleetLock` and by convention you can search for a parameter named `fleetId` or annotate the parameter with a new annotation `@FleetId`.

Comment: I've created a simple project to go more deep with AOP and I've updated my question.